# Having URL without .aspx extensionStrange behavior with Facebook Multi Friend Selector

Tags: facebook

I bought and implemented this from Vatlab:
- http://demo.faceconn.net/InviteFriends.aspx

If you go here and click "SKIP" button on the top right, it works:
- http://www.leapup.com.au/invite.aspx

On the other hand if you go here and click "SKIP", it throws an error page:
- http://www.uniquevolve.com/Webform1.aspx

There is not a lot of difference between the two except for the AppID, APIKey, Secret, AppName and AppCanvasUrl. So I'm inclined to think that Vatlab's code is buggy.. even he has no clue how to fix it.

Do you know a good ASP .Net implementation of Facebook Multi Friend Selector?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly DISCOURAGE anyone to buy from Vatlab. There is no 30-days money back guarantee and the support lasts for 6 months only. Also it did not work for me as the code was buggy. It tries to use FBML language.

I would suggest using this IFRAME solution instead:

http://fbtutorial.computerbeacon.net/section1/fbconnect